# How can I store the arguments of a variadic type?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to call this foo function from the action member function, instead of the constructor.
For that, I have to store the values somewhere.
I can not figure out the syntax to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
void foo(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout<<a<<b;
}
template<typename... Args>
struct Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Args... args){foo(args...);}
    void action(){}
private:
    //Args... ?
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int,int> x(1,2);
}
```

Comment: Check out [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: ... and/or [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: ... and [std::forward](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward)

Comment: Mhm... I was wondering why do you need such a thing? Can some one explain?

Comment: ... and `std::clinic`.

Comment: ...and `[]{ foo(1,2); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can forego the templatisation of `Foo` with `std::function` and `std::bind`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void foo(int a, int b)
{
  std::cout<<a<<b;
}

struct Foo
{
public:
  template<typename... Args>
  Foo(Args&&... args)
      // bind the arguments to foo
    : func_(std::bind(foo, std::forward<Args>(args)...)) { }

  // then you're able to call it later without knowing what was bound to what.
  void action(){ func_(); }

private:
  std::function<void()> func_;
};

int main()
{
  Foo x(1,2);

  x.action();
}
```

EDIT: To answer the comment, to bind a constructor I'd use a function template like

```
template<typename T, typename... Args> T *make_new(Args&&... args) {
  return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

and then

```
std::bind(make_new<SomeClass, Args...>, std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

**Important style note:** Consider binding to `std::make_shared` or `std::make_unique` (if you can use C++14) instead, to get the benefit of smart pointers for free.

Comment: Note that creator of `Foo` may need to use `std::ref` sometimes.

Comment: What if the function is actually the constructor for another object?
I have to to call new Type(args).

Comment: @manasij7479 Constructors are unnamed member functions and cannot be directly invoked like a function call. You'll need to create a helper function that is called to invoke `new T(args...)`.

Comment: @manasij7479: That's a new-expression you are talking about, not just a constructor call (Constructors are not directly callable anyway, and cannot have their address taken). You need to put it into a function, for example with a lambda.